# Asking turtles for minimum of variable on the other-end of links

Tags: netlogo

I am currently working on a problem where I have two agent-sets: buyers and sellers and the sellers are linked-to buyers. My question is: How to ask the buyers to choose the minimum of seller's variable (price).

[image: example of the links and agentsets]

I thought I can do it through primitives like:

```
ask buyers with [count my-in-links > 1][
    min-one-of price of other-end ;; something like this, this don't work obviously just wanted to show you my idea.
]
```

or:

```
ask buyers with [count my-in-links > 1][
     if min-one-of in-link-neighbors of in-link-neighbors price  < 1[
       set color yellow
     ]
  ]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need something like this:

```
... min-one-of in-link-neighbors [price]
```

e.g., if you want to store the cheapest seller as an agent in a variable:

```
ask buyers with [count my-in-links > 1][
  let cheapest-seller min-one-of in-link-neighbors [price]
]
```

Or you can access the price of this seller directly and for example store it in a variable:

```
ask buyers with [count my-in-links > 1][
  let cheapest-price [price] of min-one-of in-link-neighbors [price]
]
```